# vb6 using selenium is faulty " Class not registered 80040154"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vb6

I use windows 10 64bit, office 32bit 2016, when i access selenium using VBA in excel it works, but when i do it on vb6 i get an error:

[image]

I see on youtube that someone can use vb6 + selenium.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
        GetData
End Sub

Function GetData()
    Dim d As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    d.Get "https://www.google.com/"
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: If you go to the Object Browser window in the VB6 IDE can you navigate to the Selenium library and inspect its types?

Comment: I fixed the error by removing VB6 admin rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had your problem and it's easy to solve:
Run VB6 not in compatibility mode and not in administrator mode.

you have to locate the file vb6.exe and, with the right click, select 'properties' and go to the 'compatibility' tab.
at this point uncheck 'run in compatibility mode' and 'run as administrator'

[property of vb6.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6acG.png)

Comment: The attached image is in a different language, can you explain it in words in your answer as the user who posting the question would not understand.

Comment: Done, thanks. Im sorry